# Using "that" instead of "who", as a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, that, who

When referring to a person, why would anyone use "that" instead of "who"?

For example:
"The musician that won the award is very creative."
instead of:
"The musician who won the award is very creative."

To me, using "that" in this case sounds like saying: "It won the award", which sounds somewhat disrespectful. What am I missing?

Comment: As a subordinator, _that_ can refer to any entity, animate or inanimate. It has no closer affinity to things than to humans.

Comment: That's right. The demonstrative pronoun _that_ is neuter when used alone, but the word _that_ used in relative clauses is not a pronoun. It's a complementizer and it can be used instead of a relative pronoun -- any relative pronoun: _who, which, where, when, why,_ even _how_, which can't be used as a relative pronoun, though _that_ can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jacobean England, the choice of *that* — and occasionally even *which* — with a personal antecedent seems merely a stylistic one, as a sampling from the first book of the [King James Bible](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=simple&format=Long&q1=that&restrict=All&size=All) demonstrates:

for common nouns:

> And in the fourteenth year came Chedorlaomer, and *the kings that* were with him… Gen 14.2
>   And they smote *the men that* were at the door of the house with blindness, both small and great… Gen 19.2
>   And Abraham called the name of *his son that* was born unto him, whom Sarah bare to him, Isaac. — Gen 21.1
>   Let me now leave with thee some of *the folk that* are with me. — Gen 33.5
>   …all *the prisoners that* were in the prison; 39.14
>   And he asked *Pharaoh's officers* that were with him… 40.2
>   All *the souls that* came with Jacob into Egypt, *which came* out of his loins, 46.2

for the epithet substituting for the Tetragrammaton, the four-consonant divine name:

> …I am *the LORD that* brought thee out of Ur of the Chaldees… Gen 15.2
>   *The LORD God of heaven, which* took me from my father's house, … , and *which* spake unto me, and *that* sware unto me, saying, Unto thy seed will I give this land … — Gen 24.4

for pronouns, personal and otherwise:

> And I will bless *them that* bless thee, and curse *him that* curseth thee… — Gen 12.3
>   So now it was not *you that* sent me hither, but God. — Gen 45.3
>
> cursed be *every one that* curseth thee, and blessed be *he that* blesseth thee. — Gen 27.10
>   We cannot do this thing, to give our sister to *one that* is uncircumcised;… — Gen 34.2
>   Then Joseph could not refrain himself before *all them that* stood by him… — Gen 45.2
>   And Joseph returned into Egypt, he, and his brethren, and *all that* went up with him to bury his father… Gen 50.1

Google Books queries show, however, that since roughly 1900 there has been an increasing preference for *who*. This is especially marked for indefinite pronouns:

[*someone, everyone, anyone, no one*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone+who%2Csomeone+that%2Ceveryone+who%2Ceveryone+that%2Canyone+who%2Canyone+that%2Cno+one+who%2Cno+one+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomeone%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomeone%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceveryone%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceveryone%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyone%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyone%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20one%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20one%20that%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

[*somebody, anybody, nobody*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=somebody+who%2Csomebody+that%2Canybody+who%2Canybody+that%2Cnobody+who%2Cnobody+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomebody%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomebody%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canybody%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canybody%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnobody%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnobody%20that%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

The preference is also clear for common nouns such as [*doctor, student, officer*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+doctor+who%2Cthe+doctor+that%2Cthe+officer+who%2Cthe+officer+that%2Cthe+student+that%2Cthe+student+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20doctor%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20doctor%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20officer%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20officer%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20student%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20student%20who%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

or [*man, woman, child*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+man+who%2C+the+man+that%2C+the+woman+who%2Cthe+woman+that%2Cthe+child+who%2Cthe+child+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20man%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20man%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20woman%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20woman%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20child%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20child%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20man%20who%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20man%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20woman%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20woman%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20child%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20child%20that%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

In contrast, with nouns denoting groups of people such as [*team, jury* or *committee*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+jury+who%2Cthe+jury+that%2Cthe+committee+who%2Cthe+committee+that%2Cthe+team+who%2C+the+team+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20jury%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20jury%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20committee%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20committee%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20team%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20team%20that%3B%2Cc0), *that* is preferred:

[image]

A preference, however strong, may or may not be distilled into a grammar rule, though there are any number of grammar pundits online who rail against personal *that* and a few who defend it. At this point, I would recommend avoiding *that* with indefinite pronouns and choose judiciously in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in meaning.

That - is more general, about ‘musicians in general’.

Who - is more personal - about ‘that particular musician’.

**Use ‘that’** (in this example) when you want to go on to talk about *musicians*.

**Use ‘who’** (in this example) when you want to go on to talk about *this particular musician.*

**Examples**:

**General** ‘**that** musician...’
- The musician *that* won the award is very creative. He is one of a group of musicians that appeared in the Venice Biennale.

**Specific** ‘the musician **who**...’
 - The musician *who* won the award is very creative. He often uses a special guitar with dingly bells fixed on it and sings in a high-pitched monotone.

The lack of understanding of this subtlety, has led to the idea that ‘that is for things and who is for people’, which is not the case.

https://grammarist.com/usage/that-who/

Comment: the linked page does not directly support your argument. It does dennounce the strict animate/inanimate distinction by example of *the cat, who* or *the company, who*, and nothing much more. But it's loaded with adds making up more than half its content, so I choose to remove the link. Thanks for your attention. This comment may be deleted.